# Smarty to HTML Form

Tags: html, smarty

Bit stuck here - I want to build a better looking form but the current form i have is using smarty.

How can i translate the smarty form to a html one while keeping its functionality?

The start of the form is like any other html form but the actual inputs are like this:

```
{input property=$form_fields.Positions.id}
```

My Guess would be

```
<input property="{$form_fields.positions.id}">
```

Or something along those lines

Inspect output

```
<input id="Positions" type="text" value="" class="inputString " name="Positions">
```

Comment: Can you use the browser dev tools to inspect the output?

Comment: Good idea - Always forgetting to use inspect :l - Edit Worked Thanks!

Comment: Have a look into the template for `input` and edit there.. this seems to be a custom plugin